# Mule ESB: Not able to control the flows from flow1 to flow 2

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I have a ServiceFlow and a FileFlow. As soon as the ServiceFlow (Flow1) is triggered, FileFlow (Flow2) should take all the files and process them.

Making the initial state as stopped in Flow2 works only for the first time until Mule server started  i.e., for the first triggered execution. Once the flow reaches the first trigger, if I try to keep some files in `file:inbound-endpoint` it starts processing the files.

But my scenario is based on each trigger only, so the second file has to pick the file. Please help me how to control this in Flow2.

I'm using the below code

```
<flow name="serviceFlow" doc:name="Flow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="text/xml"
        mimeType="text/xml" />
    <set-payload value="'Started Processing'" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    <async doc:name="Async">
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression">
            app.registry.FileFlow.start();
        </expression-component>
    </async>
</flow>

<flow name="FileFlow" doc:name="Flow2" initialState="stopped" >
    <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="C:\Users\Desktop\IN"/>
    <batch:execute name="businessBatch1" doc:name="Batch Execute"/>
</flow>
```

Using Mule version: 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can suggest you is to put a `<expression-component doc:name="Expression">app.registry.FileFlow.stop();</expression-component>` at the end of second flow so after the second flow is executed it will again make it's initial state "stopped" so that  you can trigger the first flow again without fear since the flow2 is stopped.

```
<flow name="serviceFlow" doc:name="Flow1">
  <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="text/xml"
        mimeType="text/xml" />
  <set-payload value="'Started Processing'" doc:name="Set Payload" />
  <async doc:name="Async">
    <expression-component doc:name="Expression">
      app.registry.FileFlow.start();
    </expression-component>
  </async>
</flow>

<flow name="FileFlow" doc:name="Flow2" initialState="stopped" >
  <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="C:\Users\Desktop\IN"/>
  <batch:execute name="businessBatch1" doc:name="Batch Execute"/>
  <expression-component doc:name="Expression">
    app.registry.FileFlow.stop();
  </expression-component>
</flow>
```

Comment: Sen: I have tried this but it is not seems to be working . Are i'm doing wrong or any other ways is there.

Comment: @Aniren:Boss Thank you,it is working fine.But in some other scenario Like for example i'm calling batch flow from my Flow2, whereas in batch flow in the ( Input Phase) i'm getting the error like  **org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream** not of correct type. It must be of type **interface java.lang.Iterable java.lang.Iterable"** it is not working. Once again i made the Batch input phase as iteratable( since my inout us xml,using java component making as list) it works. Why this strange scenario.

Comment: You need to create a separate new question on Stack Overflow posting your Mule configuration there .. We can look into it and discuss the solution there for that issue :)